# React Firestore - Retrieve all documents in an Array of document IDs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve an all documents of which document ID is within the given array. I have no issues retrieving the list of documentIDs and storing in the array. However, I am not sure on how to retrieve the documents of which ids are in the array. Please help Thanks!

portfolio doc:
**docId**{
docId: **docId**,
...
}
[image: Document]

```
  const getData = (bookmarkIds) => {
    console.log("this is " )
    console.log(bookmarkIds)
    console.log("entering" )
    const portfolioQuery = database.portfolioRef.where("docId", 'in', bookmarkIds);
    portfolioQuery.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.docs)
          if (snapshot.docs.length !== 0) {
            var id = 1;
            const tempItem = [];
    
            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
              tempItem.push({
                id: id,
                intervieweeName: doc.data().intervieweeName,
                intervieweeEmail: doc.data().intervieweeEmail,
                projectTitle: doc.data().projectTitle,
                portfolioTitle: doc.data().portfolioTitle,
                dateCreated: doc.data().dateCreated,
                fbId: doc.id
              })
    
              id++;
            })
    
            setPortfolioData(tempItem)
          }
        })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserData = database.usersRef.where("email", "==", currentUser.email);

    const bookmarkArray = [];
    const unsub = getUserData.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) =>{
            bookmarkArray.push(doc.data().bookmarkIds);
        })
        
        console.log(bookmarkArray);
        getData(bookmarkArray)
    })

    return unsub;
  }, [currentUser.email]);
```

Based on my current code above, I am receiving the following (Not getting any error just a blank return):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I made a double array by doing

```
bookmarkArray.push(doc.data().bookmarkIds);
```

solved by doing

```
bookmarkArray = doc.data().bookmarkIds;
```